# Prolog Error: Out of Local Stack in factorial

Tags: prolog, factorial

I'm trying to make a factorial code in prolog but am getting error of out of local stack, that is, it is stuck in infinite loop. I can't understand how.
Here is my code:

```
fact(0,1).
fact(1,1).

fact(X,Y):- X\==0, A=X-1, fact(A,Z), Y=X*Z.
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the `A=X-1`, and later the `Y=X*Z`. The great thing about the Prolog top level is that you can easily try out what your code does:

```
?- A = X-1.
A = X-1.

?- A = 5-1.
A = 5-1.
```

Apparently, Prolog is mocking us :). The `=` operator is used for unification; if you want to do arithmetic, you must use `is/2`:

```
?- is(A, -(5, 1)).
A = 4.
```

usually written as:

```
?- A is 5-1.
A = 4.
```

This just to show you that an expression is a term, and is evaluates the term in its second argument:

```
?- Expr = X-1, X = 3, Result is Expr.
Expr = 3-1,
X = 3,
Result = 2.
```

To your definition for factorial: it should work if you fix the arithmetic. Note that it would be cleaner if the condition for `X` at the beginning says `X > 1` instead of `X \== 0`: what does your current program do for `fact(1,F)`, and how many answers do you get?